# Can python output multiple random numbers? How can they be uniformly distributed and also be random?

Tags: python, random

I have started to learn python. I am using the book "Python scripting for computational science." I am trying to write a program for

```
"Write a script that prints a uniformly distributed random number between
−1 and 1. The number should be written with four decimals as implied by
the %.4f format."
```

I am using random.uniform to get the random number. But I can't find a function to get more than one random number. For example my code is

```
print random.uniform(-1, 1)
```

It gives the output 0.238638833859. But I want more than one uniform random number. Can any body tell me a function?
One more thing, I want to learn python for scripting purpose. So can anybody suggest a good book? I want to use python for web automation. The book I am using is not ideal for that. Kindly suggest me good book.

Comment: If you want to do something more than once, you need to learn about "loops". For a book recommendation, I suggest asking at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you can get one random number by calling the method once, what's stopping you from getting several numbers by calling the method several times?

Comment: But they won't be uniformly distributed or equidistant from each other.

Comment: If they were uniformly distributed, they would not be random. The "uniformly distributed" in the description means that the implementation of the random number generator won't create patterns and that any number in the range will have an equal chance of being selected.

Comment: @mvid: ["Uniformly distributed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) is a technical term about the random distribution; it does **not** mean the numbers are deterministically spaced equally apart. So it's a bit misleading to say "If they were uniformly distributed they would not be random"; the right thing would be to say that the OP's understanding of the term "uniformly distributed" is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Try that:

```
for x in range(4):
    print '%.4f' % random.uniform(1,-1)
```

Maybe you'll enjoy the book:

[Learning Python - 4th Edition by Mark Lutz](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596158071/)

Comment: I recommend not to start learning the old `sprintf`-like syntax any more. Better use the new `format` method instead: `print "{:.4f}".format(random.uniform(1,-1))`

Answer (score 3):

Could you be looking for something like this:

```
[random.uniform(-1+x, 1+x) for x in range(10)]
```